# Why can "return" return a "return" in Kotlin?

Tags: java, return, kotlin

The question may sound silly, but there is no typo in it.

```
fun test(): Any {
    return return true
}
```

This is actually possible in Kotlin. Although the compiler warns about

> Unreachable code

for the outer return. But this is just a warning.

I don't want to compare Java with Kotlin, but I was interested whether the same would work in Java.

```
public class Test {
  // ...
  static int test() {
    return return 1;
  }
}
```

It does not!

> /Test.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
>         return return 1;
>                    ^
>   /Test.java:8: error: not a statement
>         return return 1;
>                              ^
>   2 errors

Why was Kotlin designed this way?

Comment: Kotlin is expression-based, so most things are expressions and can be used as arguments to other expressions, including `return`. Java is statement-based, so many things are statements which can only appear at the top-level. There seems to be a (very fortuitious, IMHO) trend toward expression-based languages in recent years.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`return` is an expression in Kotlin, with a return type of `Nothing`, the type that acts as a subtype of all other types. This enables you to, for example, do this in a type safe way and without extra lines of `null` checks:

```
fun getInt(): Int? = ...

fun printInt() {
    val int: Int = getInt() ?: return
    println(int)
}
```

The type of `getInt() ?: return` can be `Int` here, because that's the closest common supertype of the two sides of the Elvis operator, thanks to `Nothing` being a subtype of `Int`.

The same thing applies for `throw`, which you can also use neatly with the `Elvis` operator to indicate that you want to cancel execution on a `null` value without having to worry about types later.

This results in an odd quirk where things like

```
fun x(): Int {
    return return throw return throw throw return 0
}
```

are valid syntax, because the `Nothing` type makes each of the expressions valid read from right to left. What will actually happen is that `return 0` will execute and the rest of the code will never be reached, as the compiler warns.

Comment: actually the last part `throw throw return 0` is not marked as unreachable

Comment: Other `Nothing` typed expressions are `continue` and `break`.

Answer (score 10):

Because the `return` statement is an expression that returns `Nothing`. As a result, the following also compiles:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val r = return
}
```

It's stated in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html):

> Kotlin has three structural jump expressions:
>
> - `return`. By default returns from the nearest enclosing function or anonymous function.
>     [...]
>
> All of these expressions can be used as part of larger expressions:
>
> ```
> val s = person.name ?: return
> ```
>
> The type of these expressions is the `Nothing` type.

Since `Nothing` is a subtype of any other type, it has the power of making weird statements, like the one in your question, valid although they appear to be very wrong...

There was actually a funny talk at [KotlinConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukwVzLq_pHk) taking a look at interesting things like the following:

```
fun getText(): String {
  val s = return throw return "Hello"
}

println(getText())
//prints "Hello"
```

Comment: I know that "return" returns Nothing, that's why the compiler says "Unreachable code".

Comment: Then if you already understand this, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I understand that I can return Nothing in general, but this does not explain why return itself should return Nothing. Being able to use return in an expression on the other hand, sounds like a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @WilliMentzel Keep a close eye on the distinction between "makes the current function return with the given value" and "evaluates to the given value". The expression `return 1` evaluates to `Nothing` and, as a side effect, makes the current function return with the value `1`. Given the nature of the side effect, no code can ever observe the result of evaluating a `return` expression.